# problem with final part of this residue integral.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

evaluate $I=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{k+sin\theta} $. where $k>1$.

is my approach below correct? I am stuck at the final step of this.
let $c$ be unit circle as $z=e^{i\theta}$ then
$I=\int_c \frac{-iz^{-1}dz}{k+(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i})}=\int_c \frac{2dz}{z^2+2ikz-2}$
Now I am going to locate points at which the integrand is not analytic in unit circle, for $K>1$. I can not decide what are those points.
$z=\frac{-2ik\pm\sqrt{8-4k^2}}{2}$ but how can I decide what are the points in unit circle?

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in simplifying the denominator. The constant term is $-1$, not $-2$. This yields

$$
z=\frac{-2\mathrm ik\pm\sqrt{4-4k^2}}2=\mathrm i(-k\pm\sqrt{k^2-1})\;.
$$

Since $k\gt1$, exactly one of these two roots is in the unit circle, namely

$$
\mathrm i(-k+\sqrt{k^2-1})\;.
$$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much.